# Rename multiple columns by names

Tags: r, dataframe, rename, r-faq

Someone should have asked this already, but I couldn't find an answer. Say I have:

```
x = data.frame(q=1,w=2,e=3, ...and many many columns...)
```

what is the most elegant way to rename an arbitrary subset of columns, whose position I don't necessarily know, into some other arbitrary names?

e.g. Say I want to rename `"q"` and `"e"` into `"A"` and `"B"`, what is the most elegant code to do this?

Obviously, I can do a loop:

```
oldnames = c("q","e")
newnames = c("A","B")
for(i in 1:2) names(x)[names(x) == oldnames[i]] = newnames[i]
```

But I wonder if there is a better way? Maybe using some of the packages? (`plyr::rename` etc.)

Answer (score 129, accepted):

`setnames` from the `data.table`package will work on `data.frame`s or `data.table`s

```
library(data.table)
d <- data.frame(a=1:2,b=2:3,d=4:5)
setnames(d, old = c('a','d'), new = c('anew','dnew'))
d


 #   anew b dnew
 # 1    1 2    4
 # 2    2 3    5
```

Note that changes are made by reference, so no copying (even for data.frames!)

Comment: For late arrivals here - Also take a look at [Joel's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36010381/4606130) below which covers checking for existing columns in case you have a list of name changes which may not all be present e.g. `old = c("a", "d", "e")`

Comment: I wonder, does this work if you only wish to rename a subset / some of the columns instead of all of them? So if I had a data frame of ten columns and wished to rename _id_firstname to firstname and _id_lastname to lastname but leave the remaining eight columns untouched, can I do this or do I have to list all columns?

Comment: @MusTheDataGuy you supply the subset of new and old names, and it will work.

Comment: @mnel I need to change the variable names of a subset as @Mus asked. However, the code above did not work for a subset of data. @Gorka's answer with ```rename_at()``` worked for changing variable names of a subset.

Comment: @micstr `skip_absent=TRUE` :)

Answer (score 142):

With dplyr you would do:

```
library(dplyr)

df = data.frame(q = 1, w = 2, e = 3)
    
df %>% rename(A = q, B = e)

#  A w B
#1 1 2 3
```

Or if you want to use vectors, as suggested by @Jelena-bioinf:

```
library(dplyr)

df = data.frame(q = 1, w = 2, e = 3)

oldnames = c("q","e")
newnames = c("A","B")

df %>% rename_at(vars(oldnames), ~ newnames)

#  A w B
#1 1 2 3
```

[L. D. Nicolas May](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3367614/l-d-nicolas-may) suggested a change given `rename_at` is being superseded by `rename_with`:

```
df %>% 
  rename_with(~ newnames[which(oldnames == .x)], .cols = oldnames)

#  A w B
#1 1 2 3
```

Comment: the user asked about passing `old` and `new` names as vectors, I think

Comment: Thanks @Jelena-bioinf. I amended the answer to include your suggestion.

Comment: Could you please explain the meaning of the ~(tilde) and where ".x" comes from in the rename_with example?

Comment: `rename_with` can use either a function or a formula to rename all columns given as the `.cols` argument. For example `rename_with(iris, toupper, starts_with("Petal"))` is equivalent to `rename_with(iris, ~ toupper(.x), starts_with("Petal"))` .

Comment: Unclear, terrible syntax, this solution is just terrible, suppose I have to rename a column called "2012 (%)" in "2012": trying to guess what your solution means in real life based on this example is just impossible. rename() is just terrible in general.

Answer (score 45):

Another solution for dataframes which are not too large is (building on @thelatemail answer):

```
x <- data.frame(q=1,w=2,e=3)

> x
  q w e
1 1 2 3

colnames(x) <- c("A","w","B")

> x
  A w B
1 1 2 3
```

Alternatively, you can also use:

```
names(x) <- c("C","w","D")

> x
  C w D
1 1 2 3
```

Furthermore, you can also rename a subset of the columnnames:

```
names(x)[2:3] <- c("E","F")

> x
  C E F
1 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 33):

Here is the most efficient way I have found to rename multiple columns using a combination of `purrr::set_names()` and a few `stringr` operations.

```
library(tidyverse)

# Make a tibble with bad names
data <- tibble(
    `Bad NameS 1` = letters[1:10],
    `bAd NameS 2` = rnorm(10)
)

data 
# A tibble: 10 x 2
   `Bad NameS 1` `bAd NameS 2`
   <chr>                 <dbl>
 1 a                    -0.840
 2 b                    -1.56 
 3 c                    -0.625
 4 d                     0.506
 5 e                    -1.52 
 6 f                    -0.212
 7 g                    -1.50 
 8 h                    -1.53 
 9 i                     0.420
 10 j                     0.957

# Use purrr::set_names() with annonymous function of stringr operations
data %>%
    set_names(~ str_to_lower(.) %>%
                  str_replace_all(" ", "_") %>%
                  str_replace_all("bad", "good"))

# A tibble: 10 x 2
   good_names_1 good_names_2
   <chr>               <dbl>
 1 a                  -0.840
 2 b                  -1.56 
 3 c                  -0.625
 4 d                   0.506
 5 e                  -1.52 
 6 f                  -0.212
 7 g                  -1.50 
 8 h                  -1.53 
 9 i                   0.420
10 j                   0.957
```

Comment: This should be the answer, but could you should also probably expand on what the `~` and `.` arguments in the `set_names()` pipe do.

Comment: In some cases, you need to explicitly type `purrr::set_names()`.

Comment: @DaveRGP when using `purrr` functions, the tilde `~` means "for each column". The `.` is dplyr syntax for LHS = left hand side of the pipe, i.e the reference to the object which is piped, in this case `data`.

Comment: The tilde `~` is a formula. You can also use a function call and pass the arguments to the `...` argument of `set_names` for example `rlang::set_names(head(iris), paste0, "_hi")` is equivalent to `rlang::set_names(head(iris), ~ paste0(.x, "_hi"))`.

Comment: `purrr::set_names()` got me today. thanks Levi!

Answer (score 32):

#### Update dplyr 1.0.0

The newest dplyr version became more flexible by adding `rename_with()` where `_with`  refers to a function as input. The *trick* is to reformulate the character vector `newnames` into a formula (by `~`), so it would be equivalent to `function(x) return (newnames)`.

In my subjective opinion, that is the most elegant dplyr expression.
Update: thanks to @desval, the oldnames vector must be wrapped by `all_of` to include all its elements:

```
# shortest & most elegant expression
df %>% rename_with(~ newnames, all_of(oldnames))

A w B
1 1 2 3
```

#### Side note:

If you reverse the order, either argument .fn must be specified as .fn is expected before .cols argument:

```
df %>% rename_with(oldnames, .fn = ~ newnames)

A w B
1 1 2 3
```

or specify argument .col:

```
 df %>% rename_with(.col = oldnames, ~ newnames)

A w B
1 1 2 3
```

Comment: it looks like this answer returns a warning at present, and will return an error in the future, because of the ambiguity when using an external vector inside select https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/faq-external-vector.html.  This should fix it ```df %>% rename_with(~ newnames, all_of(oldnames))```

Comment: Could you provide a concrete example? I can't get any replacement for `newnames` or `oldnames` to work.

Answer (score 14):

So I recently ran into this myself, if you're not sure if the columns exist and only want to rename those that do:

```
existing <- match(oldNames,names(x))
names(x)[na.omit(existing)] <- newNames[which(!is.na(existing))]
```

Answer (score 11):

Building on @user3114046's answer:

```
x <- data.frame(q=1,w=2,e=3)
x
#  q w e
#1 1 2 3

names(x)[match(oldnames, names(x))] <- newnames

x
#  A w B
#1 1 2 3
```

This won't be reliant on a specific ordering of columns in the `x` dataset.

Comment: I have upvoted your answer, but I still wonder if there is an even more elegant way to do this, particularly methods that rename by name, instead of by position

Comment: @qoheleth - it is renaming by name! There is no input here that is a positional vector as `match` takes care of that. The best you're going to do is probably @mnel's `setnames` answer.

Comment: it is still sort of renaming by position because, as you said, even though I don't have to explicitly specify a position vector, `match` is still a position oriented command. In this spirit, I deemed @user3114046's answer position based as well (even thought the `%in%` command takes care (or tries to) of things). Of course, I suppose you can argue all commands are position oriented when we drill down to the low level mechanism.... but that's not what I mean... the data.table answer is great because there is no multiple calling of the `name` commands.

Answer (score 8):

You can use a named vector. Below two options (with base R and dplyr).

base R, via subsetting:

```r
x = data.frame(q = 1, w = 2, e = 3) 

rename_vec <- c(q = "A", e = "B")
## vector of same length as names(x) which returns NA if there is no match to names(x)
which_rename <- rename_vec[names(x)]
## simple ifelse where names(x) will be renamed for every non-NA 
names(x) <- ifelse(is.na(which_rename), names(x), which_rename)

x
#>   A w B
#> 1 1 2 3
```

Or a `dplyr` option with `!!!`:

```
library(dplyr)

rename_vec <- c(A = "q", B = "e") # the names are just the other way round than in the base R way!

x %>% rename(!!!rename_vec)
#>   A w B
#> 1 1 2 3
```

The latter works because the **'big-bang'** operator `!!!` is forcing evaluation of a list or a vector.

`` ?`!!` ``

> !!! forces-splice a list of objects. The elements of the list are
> spliced in place, meaning that they each become one single argument.

Comment: don't understand how this works - `!!!oldnames` returns `c("A", "B")` but which logic transforms this into `c("A", "w", "B")`??

Comment: @AgileBean I don't know where you found that !!!oldnames would return a vector. It is used to force non-standard evaluation of multiple arguments in dplyr. see `?\`!!\`` `Use \`!!!\` to add multiple arguments to a function. Its argument should evaluate to a list or vector: args <- list(1:3, na.rm = TRUE) ; quo(mean(!!!args))`. I think I'll add this explanation to the answer. Cheers for bringing it up

Answer (score 6):

```
names(x)[names(x) %in% c("q","e")]<-c("A","B")
```

Comment: Not quite, because as I said, I don't necessarily know the position of the columns, your solution only works if `oldnames` is sorted so that `oldnames[i]` occurs before `oldnames[j]` for i<j.

Answer (score 5):

There are a few answers mentioning the functions `dplyr::rename_with` and `rlang::set_names` already. By they are separate. this answer illustrates the differences between the two and the use of functions and formulas to rename columns.

`rename_with` from the `dplyr` package can use either a function or a formula
to rename a selection of columns given as the `.cols` argument. For example passing the function name `toupper`:

```
library(dplyr)
rename_with(head(iris), toupper, starts_with("Petal"))
```

Is equivalent to passing the formula `~ toupper(.x)`:

```
rename_with(head(iris), ~ toupper(.x), starts_with("Petal"))
```

When renaming all columns, you can also use `set_names` from the rlang package. To make a different example, let's use `paste0` as a renaming function. `pasteO` takes 2 arguments, as a result there are different ways to pass the second argument depending on whether we use a function or a formula.

```
rlang::set_names(head(iris), paste0, "_hi")
rlang::set_names(head(iris), ~ paste0(.x, "_hi"))
```

The same can be achieved with `rename_with` by passing the data frame as first
argument `.data`, the function as second argument `.fn`, all columns as third
argument `.cols=everything()` and the function parameters as the fourth
argument `...`. Alternatively you can place the second, third and fourth
arguments in a formula given as the second argument.

```
rename_with(head(iris), paste0, everything(), "_hi")
rename_with(head(iris), ~ paste0(.x, "_hi"))
```

`rename_with` only works with data frames. `set_names` is more generic and can
also perform vector renaming

```
rlang::set_names(1:4, c("a", "b", "c", "d"))
```

Answer (score 4):

This would change all the occurrences of those letters in all names:

```
 names(x) <- gsub("q", "A", gsub("e", "B", names(x) ) )
```

Comment: I don't think this is particularly elegant once you get past a couple of rename instances.

Comment: I'm just not good enough to whip up a `gsubfn` answer. Perhaps G.Grothendieck will come by. He is the regex-meister.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the name set, save it as a list, and then do your bulk renaming on the string. A good example of this is when you are doing a long to wide transition on a dataset:

```
names(labWide)
      Lab1    Lab10    Lab11    Lab12    Lab13    Lab14    Lab15    Lab16
1 35.75366 22.79493 30.32075 34.25637 30.66477 32.04059 24.46663 22.53063

nameVec <- names(labWide)
nameVec <- gsub("Lab","LabLat",nameVec)

names(labWide) <- nameVec
"LabLat1"  "LabLat10" "LabLat11" "LabLat12" "LabLat13" "LabLat14""LabLat15"    "LabLat16" "
```

Answer (score 3):

If the table contains two columns with the same name then the code goes like this,

```
rename(df,newname=oldname.x,newname=oldname.y)
```

Answer (score 2):

Sidenote, if you want to concatenate one string to all of the column names, you can just use this simple code.

```
colnames(df) <- paste("renamed_",colnames(df),sep="")
```

Answer (score 1):

Lot's of sort-of-answers, so I just wrote the function so you can copy/paste.

```r
rename <- function(x, old_names, new_names) {
    stopifnot(length(old_names) == length(new_names))
    # pull out the names that are actually in x
    old_nms <- old_names[old_names %in% names(x)]
    new_nms <- new_names[old_names %in% names(x)]

    # call out the column names that don't exist
    not_nms <- setdiff(old_names, old_nms)
    if(length(not_nms) > 0) {
        msg <- paste(paste(not_nms, collapse = ", "), 
            "are not columns in the dataframe, so won't be renamed.")
        warning(msg)
    }

    # rename
    names(x)[names(x) %in% old_nms] <- new_nms
    x
}

 x = data.frame(q = 1, w = 2, e = 3)
 rename(x, c("q", "e"), c("Q", "E"))

   Q w E
 1 1 2 3
```

Comment: `rename(x, c("q", "e"), c("Q", "E"))` no longer seems to work in dplyr rename?

Answer (score 0):

If one row of the data contains the names you want to change all columns to you can do

```
names(data) <- data[row,]
```

Given `data` is your dataframe and `row` is the row number containing the new values.

Then you can remove the row containing the names with

```
data <- data[-row,]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the function that you need:
Then just pass the x in a rename(X) and it will rename all values that appear and if it isn't in there it won't error

```
rename <-function(x){
  oldNames = c("a","b","c")
  newNames = c("d","e","f")
  existing <- match(oldNames,names(x))
  names(x)[na.omit(existing)] <- newNames[which(!is.na(existing))]
  return(x)
}
```

Comment: this seems to be the same as [JoelKuiper's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36010381/2204410), but then reframed as function .....

Answer (score 0):

Many good answers above using specialized packages. This is a simple way of doing it only with base R.

```
df.rename.cols <- function(df, col2.list) {
  tlist <- transpose(col2.list)
    
  names(df)[which(names(df) %in% tlist[[1]])] <- tlist[[2]]

  df
}
```

Here is an example:

```
df1 <- data.frame(A = c(1, 2), B = c(3, 4), C = c(5, 6), D = c(7, 8))
col.list <- list(c("A", "NewA"), c("C", "NewC"))
df.rename.cols(df1, col.list)

  NewA B NewC D
1    1 3    5 7
2    2 4    6 8
```

Answer (score 0):

For execution time purposes ,  I would like to suggest to use data tables structure:

```html
> df = data.table(x = 1:10, y = 3:12, z = 4:13)
> oldnames = c("x","y","z")
> newnames = c("X","Y","Z")
> library(microbenchmark)
> library(data.table)
> library(dplyr)
> microbenchmark(dplyr_1 = df %>% rename_at(vars(oldnames), ~ newnames) ,
+                dplyr_2 = df %>% rename(X=x,Y=y,Z=z) ,
+                data_tabl1= setnames(copy(df), old = c("x","y","z") , new = c("X","Y","Z")),
+                times = 100) 
Unit: microseconds
       expr    min      lq     mean  median      uq     max neval
    dplyr_1 5760.3 6523.00 7092.538 6864.35 7210.45 17935.9   100
    dplyr_2 2536.4 2788.40 3078.609 3010.65 3282.05  4689.8   100
 data_tabl1  170.0  218.45  368.261  243.85  274.40 12351.7   100
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently built off of [@agile bean](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7769076/agile-bean)'s answer (using `rename_with`, formerly `rename_at`) to build a function which changes column names if they exist in the data frame, such that one can make the column names of heterogeneous data frames match each other when applicable.

The looping can surely be improved, but figured I'd share for posterity.

###### create example data frame:

```
x= structure(list(observation_date = structure(c(18526L, 18784L, 
17601L), class = c("IDate", "Date")), year = c(2020L, 2021L, 
2018L)), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(id = NA_integer_, 
common_name = NA_integer_, scientific_name = NA_integer_, observation_count = NA_integer_, 
country = NA_integer_, country_code = NA_integer_, state = NA_integer_, 
state_code = NA_integer_, county = NA_integer_, county_code = NA_integer_, 
observation_date = NA_integer_, time_observations_started = NA_integer_, 
observer_id = NA_integer_, sampling_event_identifier = NA_integer_, 
protocol_type = NA_integer_, protocol_code = NA_integer_, duration_minutes = NA_integer_, 
effort_distance_km = NA_integer_, effort_area_ha = NA_integer_, 
number_observers = NA_integer_, all_species_reported = NA_integer_, 
group_identifier = NA_integer_, year = NA_integer_, checklist_id = NA_integer_, 
yday = NA_integer_), class = "factor", .Label = c("constant", 
"aggregate", "identity")), row.names = c("3", "3.1", "3.2"), class = "data.frame")
```

###### function

```
match_col_names <- function(x){

  col_names <- list(date = c("observation_date", "date"),
                    C =    c("observation_count", "count","routetotal"),
                    yday  = c("dayofyear"),
                    latitude  = c("lat"),
                    longitude = c("lon","long")
                    )

  for(i in seq_along(col_names)){
    newname=names(col_names)[i]
    oldnames=col_names[[i]]

  toreplace = names(x)[which(names(x) %in% oldnames)]
  x <- x %>%
    rename_with(~newname, toreplace)
}

return(x)

}
```

###### apply function

```
x <- match_col_names(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

A *base* way using `setNames` making use that `[]` will take the first match.

```
names(x) <- setNames(c(newnames, names(x)), c(oldnames, names(x)))[names(x)]

names(x) <- (\(.) setNames(c(newnames, .), c(oldnames, .))[.])(names(x)) #Variant

x
#  A w B
#1 1 2 3
```

Using `transform`.

```
names(x) <- do.call(transform, c(list(as.list(setNames(names(x), names(x)))),
                                 as.list(setNames(newnames, oldnames))))
```

Data

```
x = data.frame(q=1,w=2,e=3)
oldnames = c("q","e")
newnames = c("A","B")
```