# Conditional column header replacement with a data frame column in R

Tags: r, replace, tidyverse

I have merged several data frames and the headers lack clarity. I need to change them from 'Indicator' to 'NEWNAMES'

The data frame I created is called new_names and follows this pattern :

```
**NEWNAME**   **Indicator**
Housing price  Indicator1
Water Stress    WSL
```

the dataframe that needs changed is  'WS_MAT' and looks like this

```
     Country Year Indicator1 EMP.c WSL
     FR     2015  22         23   23
     USA    2019  1000       513  55
```

I tried

```
colnames(WS_MAT) <- ifelse(colnames(WS_MAT)==new_names$Indicator,new_names$NEWNAME, colnames(WS_MAT))
```

but I get an error message :
Error in dimnames(x) <- dn :
la longueur de 'dimnames' [2] n'est pas égale à l'étendue du tableau

Sorry my computer is in French, but from what I understood, it treats colnames as a function. If you have any suggestion, please let me know! thanks.

Comment: Your question is answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20987295/rename-multiple-columns-by-names. I would personally go with Gorka's answer, but that's just a personal preference.

Comment: Hey @Rmematey, thank you for flagging that. I have a few issues. My table was not a data frame, whenI convert it it changes the format of my titles e.g. My title becomes My.title . I was also looking for a conditional replacement because the new_names table is not the same length as my column headers to be replaced and has empty cells.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean, do you think you could create a reproducible example?

Comment: Actually, I looked further into the answers you the link you gave and Joey's answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/36010381/4606130 solved part of my issue. 
My data frame WS_MAT has 235 columns. I wanted to do a conditional replacement is because name replacement sheet has empty cells. E.g. 
Newname                 Indicator
Medical graduates  MEDICALGRAD
NA                           NURSEGRAD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to your suggestions @r-me-matey and pointers to other threads http://stackoverflow.com/a/36010381/4606130, I got a solution that works for me.
the data frame that needs the column name changed is **FINAL** (then renamed d).
the data frame containing the reference column and the new names is called **protocol**

```
d<-data.frame(FINAL, check.names=FALSE)
Indicator<-data.frame(colnames(FINAL))
library(data.table)
existing <- match(protocol$'Indicator',names(d))
names(d)[na.omit(existing)] <- protocol$NEWNAME[which(!is.na(existing))]
```