# Find a set of column names and replace them with new names using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have below data frame

```
library(dplyr)
data = data.frame('A' = 1:3, 'CC' = 1:3, 'DD' = 1:3, 'M' = 1:3)
```

Now let define a vectors of strings which represents a subset of column names of above data frame

```
Target_Col = c('CC', 'M')
```

Now I want to find the column names in `data` that match with `Target_Col` and then replace them with

```
paste0('Prefix_', Target_Col)
```

I prefer to do it using `dplyr` chain rule.

Is there any direct function available to perform this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `dplyr`s `rename_with`

```
library(dplyr)

rename_with(data, function(x) ifelse(x %in% Target_Col, paste0("Prefix_", x), x))
  A Prefix_CC DD Prefix_M
1 1         1  1        1
2 2         2  2        2
3 3         3  3        3
```

Answer (score 1):

Other solutions can be found here!
[clickhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20987295/rename-multiple-columns-by-names)

```
vars<-cbind.data.frame(Target_Col,paste0('Prefix_', Target_Col))

data <- data %>% 
  rename_at(vars$Target_Col, ~ vars$`paste0("Prefix_", Target_Col)`)
```

or

```
data %>% rename_with(~ paste0('Prefix_', Target_Col), all_of(Target_Col))
```

Answer (score 1):

We may use

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  rename_with(~ str_c('Prefix_', .x), all_of(Target_Col))
  A Prefix_CC DD Prefix_M
1 1         1  1        1
2 2         2  2        2
3 3         3  3        3
```